# C++ Standard Library hash code sample

Tags: c++, hash, stl, hashmap

I solved a problem to find duplicates in a list

I used the property of a set that it contains only unique members

```
set<int> s;

// insert the new item into the set
s.insert(nums[index]);

// if size does not increase there is a duplicate
if (s.size() == previousSize)
{
   DuplicateFlag = true;
   break;
}
```

Now I am trying to solve the same problem with hash functions in the Standard Library. I have sample code like this

```
#include <functional>

using namespace __gnu_cxx;
using namespace std;

hash<int> hash_fn2;
int x = 34567672;
size_t int_hash2 = hash_fn2(x);

cout << x << "   " << int_hash2 << '\n';
```

x and int_hash2 are always the same
Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It isn't clear from the code you posted why you would expect `x` and `int_hash2` to change.

Answer (score 2):

For `std::hash<int>`, it's ok to directly return the **original int value**. From the [specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), it only needs to ensure that for two different parameters `k1` and `k2` that are not equal, the probability that `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)` should be very small, approaching `1.0/std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`. Clearly returning the original value satisfies the requirement for `std::hash<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

> x and int_hash2 are always the same Am I missing something here ?

Yes.  You say *"I am trying to solve the same problem with hash functions"*, but hash functions are not functional alternatives to `std::set<>`s, and can not - by themselves - be used to solve your poroblem.  You probably want to use a `std::unordered_set<>`, which will internally use a *hash table*, using the `std::hash<>` function (by default) to help it map from elements to "buckets".  For the purposes of a hash table, a hash function for integers that returns the input is *usually* good enough, and if it's not the programmer's expected to provide their preferred alternative as a template parameter.

Anyway, all you have to do to try a hash table approach is change `std:set<int> s;` to `std::unordered_set<int> s;` in your original code.

Comment: The problem is to detect duplicates in a vector or list

Comment: @NB2345: see "You probably want to use a `std::unordered_set<>`" above: for each element in the `vector` or `list`, call `if (my_unordered_set.insert(value).second) ...newly inserted...; else ...was a duplicate...;`.  See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert).